# Create a class instance within my Django code from http request?

Tags: python, django, twilio

Using Django, I am trying to set up a sms server to store numbers based on sms responses. Through `Django` `twilio`, I was able pull the numbers and the responses.

Now I want to go into the `InteractiveConsole` and show an actual list of phone numbers from a certain list, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

File **views.py**

```
from django.http import request
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from django_twilio.request import decompose
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
from .models import Clients


@twilio_view
def sms_choice(request):
    twilio_request = decompose(request)
    contact_num = twilio_request.from_
    response = twilio_request.body
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    Clients(doctor=contact_num)
    resp.message('Thanks for subscribing')
    print(contact_num, response)
    return str(resp), Clients
```

File **models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Clients (models.Model):
    doctor = models.BigAutoField(
        primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.doctor
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a tuple here:

```
 return str(resp), Clients
```

While you should return a response instance.